# Accessing cucumber steps or parameters

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, testng

I am using `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` from spring to run cucumber test and `cucumber-testng:7.3.4`

As example:

Scenario file:

```
# Feature definition in Grehkin syntax
Feature: Is it Friday yet?
  Everybody wants to know when it's Friday

  Scenario Outline: Jira-0000: Checking whether it is Friday
    Given today is "<day>"
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet
    Then I should be told "<resp>"
    Examples:
      | day    | resp |
      | Sunday | Nope |
      | Monday | Nope |
      | Friday | Yes  |
```

Code:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/cucumber/features/Cucumber.feature", //link to features
        glue = {"cucumber/stepdefs"} // link to action code
)
public class CucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Test(dataProvider = "scenarios") // runs all scenarios at once
    public void testSampleCucumberAll(PickleWrapper pi, FeatureWrapper wr) throws Throwable {
        this.testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pi.getPickle());
    }
}
```

At some point in test, i need to retrieve either:

1. Arguments, so for this scenario file for first run it would be "Sunday,Nope", second run "Monday, Nope" and last run "Friday,Yes"
2. whole step definition e.g "Given today is Sunday", "When i ask whether it's Friday yet","Then i should be told Nope"

I can retreive step definitions using:

`pi.getPickle().getPickle().getSteps()`. however the second `getPickle()` method is package private so i cannot access it.

Is there any other way i can access the data  i need?

Thanks for help

Comment: It's not possible to do that. What are you trying to do with the information you're trying to access?

Comment: report it to another service. To log what failed and what passed

Comment: Have a look at Cucumbers plugin system. It's not very well documented at all, but if you look at the existing ones in the source code you should be able to write one. This may also be useful: https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/01/cucumber-jvm-plugin/